# Supporting api interface and web front end interface with shared logic using Vapor

Tags: swift, api, rest, vapor

I'm putting together authentication using vapor, and wondered if there's a good way to re-use logic in the routing to be used over rest api as well as a web front end.

```
struct AuthenticationController: RouteCollection {

    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
        routes.group("auth") { auth in
            auth.post("register", use: register)
            auth.post("login", use: login)
        }
        auth.group("email-verification") { emailVerificationRoutes in
            emailVerificationRoutes.post("", use: sendEmailVerification)
            emailVerificationRoutes.get("", use: verifyEmail)
        }
        ...
    }

    private func register(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<HTTPStatus> {
        ...
    }

    private func login(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<LoginResponse> {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

I'm then adding this auth collection under `api`

```
app.group("api") { api in
    try! api.register(collection: AuthenticationController())
}
```

All the return values are `EventLoopFutures` of either `HTTPStatus` when there's nothing to return, or structs that implement `Content` to return objects as json

What I'm wondering is how would be a good way to refactor out and resuse anything in auth and apply html web interfaces for it as well? So web forms for the post bits, pages for get, error responses etc. that could be served under `/auth/login` etc. as well as `/api/auth/login`

I was thinking I might be able to `flatMap` or similar the `EventLoopFuture`s returned in the methods, and convert those by returning `View`s but I'm not sure how I'd go about that.

Or would it be a case of just pulling out all the logic from `AuthenticationController`, and making a `WebAuthenticationController` route collection for example that builds similar routes with the handlers in both controllers calling out to the logic handlers?

I've tried searching but wasn't able to find any examples of reusing handlers for multiple purposes

Answer (score 1):

Well you could create a new struct conforming to `ResponseEncodable` like this:

```
struct MixedResponse: ResponseEncodable {
    var view: View?
    var response: Response?
    static func view(_ view: View) -> MixedResponse {
        MixedResponse(view: view)
    }
    static func response(_ response: Response) -> MixedResponse {
        MixedResponse(response: response)
    }
}
```

Then in your `encodeResponse` function check what is `nill` & return the relevant data:

```
func encodeResponse(for request: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
    if let view {
        //do something
    }else if let response {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Instead of returning a specific response, you just return `MixedResponse`. I highly encourage you to try `async/await` instead of Futures.

Comment: Hey thanks, the returned stuff already implements `ResponseEncodable` so I'm not sure I see the benefit of wrapping them, I can return a View or a Response/Content already. Are you suggesting the Auth controller returns both a view and a response inside the mixed response, then it can encode which ever in `encodeResponse` depending on which endpoint I add it to? (api endpoint or web)

Comment: Yes you return both, & you encode the content depending on the endpoint.

Comment: Ok thanks- just the `if let`s in the encodeResponse makes it look like you just returned one and you're checking which is nil. That should be a check on the endpoint like you say right, and neither are nil?